# How to handle router redirect with nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

i have little problem when i working on redirecting router with vue/nuxt..

in navbar im using this tag to pointing link between page..

```
<nuxt-link class="nav-link" :to="`/servers/${id }/sites/${ids}/application`">site1</nuxt-link>
<nuxt-link class="nav-link" :to="`/servers/${id}/sites/${ids}/application`">sit2</nuxt-link>
```

for example, on current page on `site1` i have url like this `http://localhost:3000/servers/3/sites/13/application`..

When i click `site2` it should redirect to `http://localhost:3000/servers/4/sites/14/application`..

but vue/nuxt not redirect me to the page, but the url is change..

If i change nav tag using `a href` instead of `nuxt-link` the page will redirect and it reload the page too, i want to use `nuxt-link` so the page do not reload when i redirect to new page..

is it posible?

Comment: try adding a `:key="$route.params.id"` to the page to trigger re-render

Comment: @LawrenceCherone im trying add `key` to application.vue on `template` tag but still not working..

Comment: it looks pretty nested but servers is the best place presuming your using a bunch of nuxt-child's

Comment: @Jazuly I'm facing the exact issue, did you figure out any solution for this ?

Comment: @Pratik149 i solve it with this `watch: { $route(to, from) { this.$router.go(to.path); } }`

it will refresh & redirect the page when have same parent in url but have diferent query..

Comment: Thanks so much for quickly responding,@Jazuly. This seems like a working solution to me, will try it and let you know if it works for me. :)

Comment: ok, hope it can solve your problem..